# generate empty e2e test with angular cli

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli

I am getting started working with angular cli,
I have understood that it can create almost all the files, but it seems it does not create empty e2e test for the new page-component.

Do I have to create manually e2e spec files ?

Comment: Currently yes, But there is a work in progress project like protractor's interactive cli which would have this feature eventually. https://github.com/igniteram/Cliptor.js